# How to connect between Simulated Vehicle and Companion Computers at the same time?

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

I was wondering if it was possible to connect to a virtual drone and physical drone at the same time, UDP and USB. This is to test ground station like functionality to be able to control multiple drones. I only have 1 physical and want to test between both.

Or to at least prove my suspicion that

```
api = local_connect()     # Get an APIConnection
all_vehicle = api.get_vehicles()
```

Does in fact give me all possible connected vehicles.

And just play with it from there.

Edit:

What my process was is looking at [MAVProxy](https://tridge.github.io/MAVProxy/) and read up on it. I can connect to a physical drone Iris+ and a virtual copter by following 
[this](http://python.dronekit.io/guide/sitl_setup.html). 
I run the instance with this command 
sim_vehicle.sh -v ArduCopter -L PLACE --map --console --out :14550
It works well and I can connect to it using MavProxy via the following command

[start up](http://python.dronekit.io/guide/getting_started.html)

```
mavproxy.py --master=127.0.0.1:14550
```

Now I can connect to the physical as well with

```
mavproxy.py --master=/dev/USB0
```

When I try to use with both

```
mavproxy.py --master=127.0.0.1:14550 --master=/dev/USB0
```

It doesn't work and I don't even know if it would work to begin with I was just trying.
All in all what i am trying to do is being able to connect to 2 drones and be able to control them with 1 ground control station.

API: [to connect to multiple vehicles](http://python.dronekit.io/automodule.html#droneapi.lib.APIConnection)

Comment: Yes, the code to get the connection should get all possible connections and you should be able to iterate them. Yes the connections should be set up using MAVProxy (outside of DroneKit itself). 

The setup problem is (probably) that you can only have one master in the network. Check the MAVProxy documentation for adding another link.

CAVEAT. I have never actually seen this running or tried it. I did ask the question internally some months ago, and my comments above were the response.

Comment: I tried just as you said. I started up the master using the local network with the 14550 port. The linked /dev/ttyUSB0. It seem to have work as a got 2 response modes(STABILIZE, ALT_HOLD). So, my assumption that I am getting 2. However, when I run the following [ApiConnection](http://pasted.co/91f1d6c9). I get 1 vehicle.

Comment: Pretty much I want to create a simple GCS from scratch to handle multiple UAVs. This is more for practice. I understand I could use all the other GCS(i.e. Mission Planner, etc), but I want to know how it is done to connect and control each UAVs directly.

Comment: Pretty much playing with it and follow as such.. Vehicle with SYSID_THISMAV = 1, do Mission A,C. Vehicle with SYSID_THISMAV = 2, do Mission B, D. Which these missions are determined by when the other drones have finished there other missions.